# Question about proof in problem with a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence which is defined as $\sqrt{a_n}$ if $a_n$ is a square number and $a_n+2$ otherwise. I am told that $a_1>1$ and I have to prove that the sequence ends with $3,5,7,9$ if the first term is odd and with $2,4$ if it is odd.

Anyways I did try to prove it but I think it only applies if $a_1=2$ in the case of even and $a_1=3$ and okay in a couple of other cases but I don't think it applies for any random $a_1>1$.

So my question is, is there any rule or theorem that makes me have  $a_1=2$ if I know it is even and $a_1=3$ in the case of odd?

Maybe it's trivial or maybe I am missing something but I would be really thankful for some help.

Answer (score 1):

For $a_1=2$ sequence is $$2 \to 4 \to 2 \to 4 \to \ldots$$

For $a_1=3$ sequence is $$3 \to 5 \to 7 \to 9 \to 3 \to \ldots$$

The sequence increases in steps of $2$ until it hits a perfect square. Thus the terms always maintain their parity.

For $a_1=2k+1$ where $m^2 < a_1 < n^2$, the terms increase in steps of $2$ until an odd square is hit. Then the sequence drops to an odd square root. This goes on and finally $3 \to 5 \to 7 \to 9 \to 3 \to \ldots$ is obtained.

Same for $a_1=2l$.

Comment: Okay so a_1 doesn't have to be 2 or 3. How can I say with certainty that the terms will hit an odd square and that if it goes on we will have the mentioned sequences, I mean in order to be 100% mathematically correct

Comment: @Annalisa $2$ is an even number, adding $2$ to any number doesn't change the parity. Odd + Even = Odd. Even + Even = Even. Similarly taking square root of a perfect square doesn't change its parity. (Odd)$^2$ = Odd. (Even)$^2$ = Even.

Comment: @Annalisa This proof is incomplete. You have to prove $2\to 4 \to 2$ and $3 \to 5 \to 7 \to 9 \to 3$ are the only two loops. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We take out all perfect squares from the sequence and form a new sequence $\{b_n\}$ and prove the following:

1. If $a_1$ is odd, thus all $b_n$'s are odd, then $b_n \ge 25 \implies b_{n+1} < b_n$.

Assume $b_n=(2m+1)^2, m \ge 2$. If $2m+1$ is a perfect square then $b_{n+1}=2m+1 < b_n$ we are done. If not, assume $(2k-1)^2 < 2m+1 < (2k+1)^2 \implies b_{n+1} = (2k+1)^2$, we now prove that $b_{n+1} = (2k+1) < (2m+1)^2=b_n$, or equivalently, $k<m$. If not, then $k\ge m$,

$$2m+1 > (2k-1)^2 \ge (2m-1)^2 \\
\implies 0 > (2m-1)^2-(2m+1) = 2m(2m-3) > 0$$ a contradiction.

2. If $a_1$ is even, thus all $b_n$'s are even, then $b_n \ge 16 \implies b_{n+1} < b_n$.

Assume $b_n = (2m)^2, m\ge 2$. If $2m$ is a perfect square then $b_{n+1} = 2m < b_n$ we are done. If not, assume $(2k-2)^2 < 2m < (2k)^2 \implies b_{n+1} = (2k)^2$, we now prove that $b_{n+1} = (2k)^2 < (2m)^2=b_n$, or equivalently, $k<m$. If not, then $k \ge m$,

$$2m > (2k-2)^2 \ge (2m-2)^2 \implies 0 > (2m-2)^2-2m \\
\implies 0 \ge (2m-2)^2-2m+2 = 2(m-1)(2m-3) > 0$$ another contradiction (note that $0> 2A \implies 0\ge 2A+2$, where $2A=(2m-2)^2-2m$ is even).

Therefore if $b_n$ is greater than $9$ the next perfect square is always smaller. Only when $b_n=4$ or $9$ do we get a loop, which is either $4\to 2 \to 4$ or $9 \to 3 \to 5 \to 7 \to 9$.